# Deploy war to Tomcat and post request makes 403 error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I run my project in IntelliJ IDE and it run and post request work
But deploy my war file to Tomcat and it run in port 8080 and work
But I make post request it return 403 forbidden
I use http://localhost:8080/mobile_app_ws/users

I tried Tomcat 9 and also 10 but still 403.

"mobile_app_ws" my war file name and also my project name

SecurityConstants.SIGN_UP_URL ="/users"

```
`@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.test")
public class MobileAppWsApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

   @Override
   protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
      return application.sources(MobileAppWsApplication.class);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(MobileAppWsApplication.class, args);
   }
```

In Securtiy

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors().and()
                .csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SecurityConstants.SIGN_UP_URL)
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SecurityConstants.VERIFICATION_EMAIL_URL)
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/**", "/swagger*/**", "/webjars/**")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers(SecurityConstants.H2_CONSOLE)
                .permitAll()
                //.antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE,"/users/**").hasAuthority("DELETE_AUTHORITY")
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .addFilter(getAuthenticationFilter())
                .addFilter(new AuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(),userRepository))
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
    }
```

In Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

  @PostMapping(consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE },
            produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public UserRes createUser(@RequestBody UserDetailsRequestModel userDetails) throws Exception {}

}
```

In pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.appsdeveloperblog.app.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>mobile_app_ws</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>mobile_app_ws</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>3.0.0</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>3.0.0</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>3.0.0</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->



        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>mobile_app_ws</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I tried in my Postman post request and it didn't return 403 forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

Check your CORS configuration and allow origins

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).